# CSS content crashes in two floated divs

Tags: css

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fadohaxu/1) 
I've been trying to create to lists which the one floats to the left and the second floats to the right, and after them there's a content of the site like in the demo. 
But the content goes up and I want to make him go lower. I tried the `<br>` but I'm sure that there's a better way to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include all necessary code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can't do lists with `<div>`, only with `<dl>`, `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags. You should read [w3schools LISTS](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp). 
Back to your problem - you could use the `clear:both` which specifies what sides are allowed to float elements. 
Float makes a lot of problem in the start for everyone, but when you understand the material, like in math - it's easy to use. I recommend you read this article. It explains very well what you need to know about floats; [CSS Tricks - ALL ABOUT FLOATS](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp).

Comment: OK so I did this: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zicariqe/1/edit) but as you see, it isn't at the same line and the sign near the lists' content is different. Can you help me? I'm beginner... Sorry and thanks!

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fadohaxu/3/edit) DON'T GET AHEAD OF YOURSELF. I learned that it isn't good to run. Good Luck!